# Using vuejs-datepicker how do I customise appearance of each date?

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vuejs-datepicker

I am using the excellent component [vuejs-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker#available-props), and as is so often the case with add-ins like this, it does 99% of what I want, but sadly that's not quite enough ...

I understand that I can set highlighted dates and disabled dates, but I would like to be able to apply different formatting to different dates (so dates in London appear in red, Manchester blue and Timbuktu green for example).

The closest I've got to this is to use the **day-cell-content** property:

```
:day-cell-content="setcell"
```

In conjunction with this function:

```
setcell(x) {      
  // put day number in italics
  return '<em>' + (x.date) + '</em>';
}
```

This works, but the only thing I can get it is the day number, and I want the date.  Other possibilities include these properties:

[image]

However, I can't get these to work, and anyway they apply to the whole calendar, and not to each individual date.

It's really frustrating, because I've had a look at the object model (sample shown below), and all I'd need to do would be to tag each day somehow!

[image]

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Custom directive?

Comment: Possibly (I just Googled them to find out what they are), but wouldn't I need to know which DOM element I was looking at (which is my problem)?

Comment: Did you see [Highlighted Dates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker#highlighted-dates)?

Comment: Yes - that just gives one set of dates.  If there were several different sets of highlighted dates, I'd be a happy bunny.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to work with the tools datepicker gives you, I think you'll have to modify your approach. I use the [`highlighted`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker#highlighted-dates) prop to highlight dates for a selected city. I put them in the [beforeCalendarHeader slot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker#beforecalendarheader) so that you can select the city with the picker open. This is pretty simple if it will work for you.

I think that if you must do custom coloring of dates, you need to get into the source of the component and [create a custom extension](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#extends).

It is not clear under your plan, what color cells would be if dates overlapped (maybe they just don't overlap in your use case).

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedCity: 'London',
    cityDates: {
      London: [
        [1, 13],
        [1, 14],
        [1, 15]
      ],
      Manchester: [
        [1, 16],
        [1, 17],
        [1, 18]
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    highlighted() {
      return this.selectedCity ? {
        dates: this.cityDates[this.selectedCity].map((pair) => new Date(2019, ...pair))
      } : {};
    }
  },
  components: {
    vuejsDatepicker
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <vuejs-datepicker :highlighted="highlighted" :open-date="new Date(2019, 1, 1)">
    <div slot="beforeCalendarHeader" class="calender-header">
      <div v-for="city in Object.keys(cityDates)">
        <label><input type="radio" v-model="selectedCity" :value="city">{{city}}</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </vuejs-datepicker>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuejs-datepicker"></script>
```

Comment: You have EXACTLY understood my problem - thanks.  I had already reached the conclusion that I need to modify my approach, and choose a city at the top.  I don't think this necessarily needs to be within the date-picker control (I've just tried it out using dynamic styles, and it works well).  Don't think I'm up to writing custom extensions - I'm only just learning Vue.JS!

PS Your Vue.js code is impressively concise!